# How does the load balancer decide how to route requests?

Tags: azure, load-balancing

The titles says nearly everything: Let's say I created 3 VM's with load balancing on port 80 in one cloud service. Now there is a request to the cloud service: How does the load balancer decide to which of these 3 VM's it should route this request? Is there a specific metric or does the load balancer routes randomly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Microsoft Azure Load Balancer is a Layer-4 type load balancer.
>   Microsoft Azure load balancer distributes load among a set of
>   available servers (virtual machines) by computing a hash function on
>   the traffic received on a given input endpoint. The hash function is
>   computed such that all the packets from the same connection (TCP or
>   UDP) end up on the same server. The Microsoft Azure Load Balancer uses
>   a 5 tuple (source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port,
>   protocol type) to calculate the hash that is used to map traffic to
>   the available servers. The hash function is chosen such that the
>   distribution of connections to servers is fairly random. However,
>   depending on traffic pattern, it is possible for different connections
>   to get mapped to the same server.

Full details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-load-balancing-services/

Comment: So if I understand right, the mapping should be randomly? Well  I just tested this: Creating a cloud service with 2 VM's, activated load balancing on port 80 but set up _different_ frontend-html-pages on these two VM's. When I now go to my.cloudapp.net within my browser (and try it multiple times from multiple PC's) then I always receive the _same_ frontend. So there is no randomness...

Comment: Interesting. Although if you are accessing from a corporate network then 4 out of the 5 tuple values will definitely be the same. I would expect source port to change, but is that certain if accessing through a firewall/proxy etc? I still read from this that in a production environment with public traffic the clients would essentially be assigned a random server, and overall the traffic would be more-or-less evenly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Load balancer may have sticky session that will route from one ip to the same backend for max 1h or something